# SQL representing populations as a percentage of Germany

Tags: sql

I'm practicing SLQ Query skills with SQLzoo.

I'm on the question which states:

> Germany (population 80 million) has the largest population of the
> countries in Europe. Austria (population 8.5 million) has 11% of the
> population of Germany.
>
> Show the name and the population of each country in Europe. Show the
> population as a percentage of the population of Germany.

My solution is the following:

```
SELECT name, 
 CONCAT(
 STR(
 ROUND( (population / (SELECT population FROM world WHERE name = 'Germany')) * 100,0)),'%') FROM world
WHERE continent = 'Europe'
```

Which produces the following table

```
name    
Albania 3%
Andorra 0%
Austria 11%
Belarus 12%
Belgium 14%
Bosnia and Herzegovina  5%
Bulgaria    9%
Croatia 5%
Czech Republic  13%
Denmark 7%
Estonia 2%
Finland 7%
France  82%
Germany 100%
Greece  14%
Hungary 12%
Iceland 0%
Ireland 6%
Italy   75%
Kazakhstan  21%
Latvia  2%
Liechtenstein   0%
Lithuania   4%
Luxembourg  1%
Macedonia   3%
Malta   1%
Moldova 4%
Monaco  0%
Montenegro  1%
Netherlands 21%
Norway  6%
Poland  48%
Portugal    13%
Romania 25%
San Marino  0%
Serbia  9%
Slovakia    7%
Slovenia    3%
Spain   58%
Sweden  12%
Switzerland 10%
Ukraine 53%
United Kingdom  79%
Vatican City    0%
```

According to online Text difference checkers, my result and the expected results are exactly the same, but for whatever reason SQLzoo rejects the answer with "Wrong answer. Some of the data is incorrect.". Is there something wrong with the query or SQLzoo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text matches, but I believe sqlzoo.net is doing type validation.

Your answer is a string `STR(...)` in your code.

If you cast the percentage calculation as an `int` it will register as correct.

The code below registers as correct on this site for question 5: https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

```
SELECT NAME, 
 
 CONCAT(CAST(ROUND(
(population / (SELECT population FROM world WHERE name = 'Germany') 
* 100),0)
as INT),'%')

AS PERCENTAGE FROM world
WHERE continent = 'Europe'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend window functions:

```
SELECT name, 
       population * 100.0 / SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'Germany' THEN population END) OVER ()
FROM world
WHERE continent = 'Europe';
```

Converting to a string with `'%'` at the end seems inappropriate in SQL, but you can do that if you like.

Answer (score 0):

This one will work

```
SELECT name, 
 CONCAT(cast(

 ROUND( (population / (SELECT population FROM world WHERE name = 'Germany')) * 100,0)as int),'%')  FROM world
WHERE continent = 'Europe'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).